# Get contents from a json page from habbo

Tags: php, json, http, curl, file-get-contents

I'm trying to get the content of a page to use it on my website.

I need the contents from [this](https://www.habbo.nl/api/public/users?name=example) link.

Then I would like to get the "figureString" from that json page,
so I can put it in [this](https://www.habbo.nl/habbo-imaging/avatarimage?figure=) link.

I tried using curl but it said that they blocked me because of ddos attempt.
I can't use file_get_contents, it says **failed to open stream: HTTP request failed!**
get_remote_data doesn't work either.

```
<?php
echo "WELCOME ".$r->habboname;

$curl_handle=curl_init();
curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://www.habbo.nl/api/public/users?name='.$r->habboname);
curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 2);
curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'myproject');
$query = curl_exec($curl_handle);
curl_close($curl_handle);

echo 'Query: '.$query;
$json = json_decode($query, true);
echo '<pre>' . print_r($json, true) . '</pre>';

echo get_remote_data('https://www.habbo.nl/api/public/users?name='.$r->habboname, true );
file_get_contents(filename)
?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got the answer:

```
$ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://www.habbo.nl/api/public/users?name='.$r->habboname);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'github.com/gerbenjacobs/habbo-api v2.2.0');
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
        // urls at /extradata/ require javascript/cookie validation, trick them.
        $data = curl_exec($ch);
        $info = curl_getinfo($ch);
        curl_close($ch);

        $json=json_decode($data, true);
        echo $json['figureString'];
```